# Scrapy doesn't return start_urls as an item

Tags: scrapy

Using the following code, I can get Scrapy to crawl the pages of a site, parse those pages and return the results of each page parse as an item for processing in a pipeline.

My issue is that I cannot work out how to process the start_url page. The start_url never gets passed to the parse_item function.

What am I missing?

```
class GenericSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Generic"
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = []

ignored_extensions = [
    # images
    'mng', 'pct', 'bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pst', 'psp', 'tif',
    'tiff', 'ai', 'drw', 'dxf', 'eps', 'ps', 'svg',

    # audio
    'mp3', 'wma', 'ogg', 'wav', 'ra', 'aac', 'mid', 'au', 'aiff',

    # office suites
    'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'doc', 'docx', 'odt', 'ods', 'odg', 'odp',

    # other
    'css', 'exe', 'bin', 'rss', 'zip', 'rar',
]


rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(deny_extensions=ignored_extensions), follow=True, callback='parse_item')
]

def __init__(self, start_url, source, *args, **kwargs):
    super(GenericSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

    #set common settings
    Bootstrap.init(self, kwargs)

    self.source = source
    self.start_urls = [start_url]
    self.allowed_domains = [urlparse.urlparse(start_url).hostname]

def parse_item(self, response):
    process response and return item ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to define [`parse_start_url`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url), something like the following should do:

```
class GenericSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Generic"
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = []
    ...
    def parse_item(self, response):
        process response and return item ....

    parse_start_url = parse_item
```